# How to get base of that vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I can't solve this problem to get BASES of vector space of this:

$$
U = {(x,y,z,w)\in R^4|y+z+w=0} \\
V = {(x,y,z,w)\in R^4|x+y=0, z=2w}
$$

and also must get $$U \cap V$$

I know that this space must contain 4 base vectors...

How to get that? Thanks!

Comment: What's the dimension of $\;U,\,V\;$? . Now, choosing wisely, though pretty expectably, values for the different parameters, pick a basis for them...and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you how to determine $\;\dim U\;$ and a basis for it, you do something similar for $\;V\;$.

The condition defining $\;U\;$ leaves us with three *free variables*: $\;x,z,w\;$ (observe that $\;x\;$ is not open to discussion, but the other two are. Instead of $\;z,w\;$ we could have chosen $\;y,\,z\;$ instead, say. I prefer the last ones in alphabetical order) . This already tells us that $\;\dim U=3=$ number of free variables.

Now pick *easy* values for the free variables. I recommend $\;0\;$ and $\;1\;$ , say:

$$\begin{align*}
\bullet\;x=0,\,z=1,\,w=0\implies y=-1\implies
\begin{pmatrix}0\\\!-1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
\bullet\;x=1,\,z=w=0\implies y=-1\implies
\begin{pmatrix}1\\\!-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
\bullet x=0,\,z=0,\,w=-1\implies y=1\implies
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\\!-1\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$

It is easy to check the above three vectors are linearly independent so you have a basis for $\;U\;$ . It's now your turn.